# Fancybox question

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox

i've been messing around with boxes recently, and i'm struggling with doing 2 siple things. Here is the tex code first.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{pression}[2][]{enhanced,title=My title,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm},attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift=-2mm},
boxed title style={size=small,colupper=black},
title={#2},#1}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\tcbset{
    skin=enhanced,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    interior style={white},
    segmentation style={black,solid,opacity=0.2,line width=1pt}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pression}{
My titleMyleMy titleMy titleMy title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{pression}
\end{document}
```

This simply creates a rounded box with title. The two things i'm would like to do are the following :

1) first i'd like that the background color of the title box is white and the title is written in black (here the background is grey and teh font is white. I've managed to put background color in white, but not to change the color font.

2) i'd like to put an image on the top of the box in the same fashion as this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vle7.jpg i.e. putting an image over the box. I've tried to put a figure in the title box but it increases its side, whereas i'd like the image just to live by itself and get only on it.

Comment: For the first: `colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black`

Comment: About the second. Will be the same image for all boxes? Is it a background image which can be covered by text? or figure on left margin with text on the right?

Comment: yes, same image for all box, and not covered by text. Just like another title box at the top of the big one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) To change the title box colors use: `coltitle=black` and `colbacktitle=white`

2) `myimage` adds the image to upper left corner. Use `xshift`, `yshift` and `scale` to adjust the position and size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\tcbset{
    myimage/.style={
        enhanced,
        overlay={
            \begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=1mm, yshift=7mm]frame.north west)}]
%               \draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle (4mm);
                \node (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=.05]{frog.jpg}};
            \end{scope}}}}

\tcbset{
    skin=enhanced,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    interior style={white},
    segmentation style={black,solid,opacity=0.2,line width=1pt}}

\newtcolorbox{pression}[2][]{
    myimage,              % image 
    coltitle=black,       % title box text color
    colbacktitle=white,   % title box background color
    title=My title,
    attach boxed title to top center={
        yshift=-3mm,
        yshifttext=-1mm},
    attach boxed title to top left={
        xshift=1cm,
        yshift=-2mm},
    boxed title style={
        size=small},
    title={#2},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{pression}{My titleMyleMy titleMy titleMy title}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{pression}

\end{document}
```