# how to design a box like this

Tags: boxes

A how to design a box like this 
B how to design a box like this
C how to design a box like this 
D how to design a box like this 
E how to design a box like this

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Unfortunately your question shows absolutely no effort. Please add a MWE to show, what you’ve tried so far. Furthermore it would be enough to apse the question once and not seven times!

Comment: A starting point could be the packages `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`.

Comment: See if this answer helps http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255897/95229

Comment: See `tcolorbox` package for creating boxes similar to what you have shown. An online version of the manual can be found on CTAN https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en    (section 10.2.2) http://mirrors.acm.jhu.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#subsubsection.10.2.2

Comment: @Tobi Only six times including the title right?

Comment: @AJN: Yep, you’re right. However at least four times to often (title plus repeating the question in the body) …

Comment: @AJN I hope he (@Peter)  is a very young person who makes his first steps into TeX, so he will learn :-)

Comment: Peter, welcome. Please improve the quality of your question. Minimal working examples were already mentioned. Personally, i consider this post to be very low quality and am even tempted to mark it as spam.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question gives no evidence of any thought or effort on behalf on the OP.

Answer (score 4):

First question... so next time, please make a Minimal Working Example... ;-)

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%% Onderzoeksvragen van het labo
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=blue!10, very thick, rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=15pt, inner ysep=15pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[draw=black, fill=blue, rounded corners, text=white, inner xsep=10pt, inner ysep=6pt, font=\sc]



\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
    blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbbblblbbblblbb blblbbblblbb
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {title};
\node[fancytitle, rotate=90, rounded corners] at (box.east) {something};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in :

[image]